# Javascript Variable and document write

Tags: javascript

I'm completely new to Javascript and trying to learn some basics

I'm making a webpage that add's up totals etc and right from the start i'm having a problem.

I'm looking at videos on lynda.com and i've also searched the net.

it's something very simple i'm trying to do.

I have a variable set to 30 and I want to display that on my page.

```
var points = 30;
document.write(points);
```

I also had 30 in double and single quotes which didn't work.

My HTML is

```
<p id="points"></p>
```

What I want to happen is I want the variable to display on site. So in this case I want 30 to display on site.

it's not at the moment.

Any help would be great.
thanks.

Comment: in what was is it not working? what are you expecting to happen? what is it that IS happening?

Comment: Could you post your entire HTML document and code?

Comment: `document.getElementById("points").textContent = points;`

Comment: Please define "didn't work". Also explain, what you're trying to achieve. Show "30" in `#points`?

Comment: Sorry guys.. I wanted it to display the var points on the html.. so I wanted 30 to display on site.

Comment: Yes, but what your code does instead? It sends the value of your variable to your neighbour using snail post?

Comment: You already told us what you want. Show us _exactly_ what you tried to load in the browser.

Comment: Daniel O. suggested below worked.. - I'm not sure what you mean by " Show us exactly what you tried to load in the browser." I gave you the html ID i was using.

Comment: Post your entire HTML file exactly as you tried to load it in the browser, including whatever `<script>` tag, so that we can see how it all fits together.

Answer (score 2):

The correct code is:

```
var points = 30;
document.getElementById('points').innerHTML = points;
```

Use innerHTML for change the HTML code and use innerText to change only the text.

Maybe you forgot to implement the script:

```
<script src="path/and/yourscriptname.js"></script>
<p id="points"></p>
```

Comment: I don't know whi gives here the bad code all the Code as an complete answer are correct for that what he want to make.

Comment: i tired.. i got a error message !!  i'll try again.

Answer (score -1):

An easier method to peek into variables at certain points is to use `console.log()`.

For example, `console.log(points);` will output `30` so your browser console.

To view the browser console, Google how to view the console for the specific browser you're using. Here's how to view it on [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console).